# How to serve js file that needs to be executed on client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do i make my script file available for html file in node js?

My server.js file looks like this

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening!');
});
```

So how do I make script in file app.js executed?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chat room</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <input type = "text" name = "message">
  </form>
</body>
<script src = "app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the javascript file in the /public or in a subdirectory of /public. Then reference that file from your index.html.

Right now index.html is looking in __dirname for the javascript file, but in your code you exposed __dirname + '/public'.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your public available folder to `public`, so your `.js`, `.css`, ... files should be in this folder. A typical structure for the public folder would be something like this:

[image]

If you have a directory structure like in above picture, you would reference your JavaScript file like this:

```
<script src = "/javascripts/app.js"></script>
```